# Cassandra and Hector broken pipe after inactivity

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu, cassandra, hector

I have a web application running on Tomcat6. After 30 or 60 minutes of inactivity, if I refresh the page I get the Broken Pipe problem (with the exceptions reported below).

I tried to look for the problem in other threads and saw an update could fix it so I updated to the latest versions (Hector 1.1, Thrift 1.1.0 and Cassandra version 1.1.4) but the problem remains. I am using the default Cassandra configs, just as it comes from `apt-get` on Ubuntu and I have just one node at the moment.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
2012-09-04 11:03:02,809 ERROR client.HThriftClient [http-8080-3,close:100] Could not flush transport (to be expected if the pool is shutting down) in close for client: CassandraClient<node1.p.cassandra.research-infrastructures.eu:9160-5>
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.flush(TFramedTransport.java:156)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.close(HThriftClient.java:98)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.close(HThriftClient.java:26)

2012-09-04 11:03:48,544 ERROR client.HThriftClient [http-8080-9,close:100] Could not flush transport (to be expected if the pool is shutting down) in close for client: CassandraClient<node1.p.cassandra.research-infrastructures.eu:9160-6>
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.flush(TFramedTransport.java:156)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your connection is timing out if you have inactivity for so long.  If you trap that exception and reconnect if you get it I'm sure the error will go away.  I would wonder if you need Cassandra if you have that much time without activity.